# remove <A> tag when domain occured

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to match specified domain in my post content then remove it, this is my regex but i can't get it work 
`/<a[^>]+href[^(*domain.com)>]+>(.*)<\/a>/`

i want to remove the a tag when specified domain occurred even if it was `domain.com?a=something` or in any other format! 
 is that could be?

Comment: Now, repeat after me. HTML cannot be parsed using regex. HTML cannot be parsed using regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: use an [html parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[^(*domain.com)>]
```

This won’t do what you would expect it to do. This will match any character that is not one of the following: `()>*.acdimno`.

What you would want to do is match exactly `domain.com`.

```
/<a[^>]+href=([^>]+domain.com[^>]+>(.*)<\/a>/
```

But then again, [don’t use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).